# Syntax error in [[ conditional expression with bash

Tags: linux, bash

When I execute this

```
regex='^[-a-z0-9]+$'
string='abcd1--'
if [[ $string =~ $regex ] -a ![ grep - "--" ]]
then 
    echo "valid"
else
    echo "not valid"
fi
```

I get

```
~$ sh t.sh 
t.sh: line 3: syntax error in conditional expression
t.sh: line 3: syntax error near `]'
t.sh: line 3: `if [[ $string =~ $regex ] -a [ grep - "--" ]]'
~$
```

It is suppose to return `not valid`.

Can someone figure out what's wrong?

Comment: Your syntax for `[[` is incorrect.

Comment: You have to execute the script using bash, not sh (which usually is (d)ash).  There is no `=~` operator using the `test` utility (which is being used by (d)ash).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're mixing `[` and `[[` syntax in a strange way.

Try:

```
if [[ ( $string =~ $regex ) && !( $string =~ "--" ) ]]
```

and check bash's man page.

Comment: note, `/usr/bin/[` is not part of bash, and its special syntax is accessible with `man test` not `man bash`.

Comment: bash does use a built-in `[` if it can. (See the `test expr` part of the bash man page.)

Comment: oh, you're right, there is a `builtin test` command, I did not know it. thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: When I search for `[[` in the bash manpage, I don't get any matches. What is the difference of `[`, `(`, and `[[` ?

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs - `[` is an "alias" for `test`, `(` is just a grouping parenthesis, `[[` is another form of conditional construct.

Comment: @SandraSchlichting see `man bash` and look under the "SHELL GRAMMAR / Compound Commands" section for `[[` and `(` as well as the "CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS" section for more information on various conditional tests. To get to these headers while browsing the manual, type `/nd Com`[Enter] (case sensitive) for Compound Commands, or `/AL EX`[Enter]`/`[Enter] for CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS (it's referenced before the actual header, so you have to go to the second instance)

Comment: `[` is a command.  Both `(` and `[[` are part of the grammar.